# Javascript - Referring to a specific array element and comparing to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am brand new to JavaScript and struggling with a quiz I am building. I am trying to compare the variable `answer` which is set by onclick with the correct answer which is an element in the `rightAnswers` array. There are 4 divs that I am using the set the variable and I've added them below.

All I want is the alert to fire so I know it's working so I can then continue adding to the function and behave as I want.

```js
var qNumber = 1;
var questions = [, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15];
var rightAnswers = [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3];
var answer = 0;

function setAnswer(choice) {
  answer = choice;
  checkAnswer();
}

function checkAnswer() {
  if (answer == rightAnswers[qNumber]) {
    alert("you got it right");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="answerA" onclick="setAnswer('1')">
  <div id="A">Answer 1 goes here</div>
</div>

<div class="answerB" onclick="setAnswer('2')">
  <div id="B">Answer 2 goes here</div>
</div>

<div class="answerC" onclick="setAnswer('3')">
  <div id="C">Answer 3 goes here</div>
</div>

<div class="answerD" onclick="setAnswer('4')">
  <div id="D">Answer 4 goes here</div>
</div>
```

It seems to be the `checkAnswer` function that is causing the issue and specifically when I add the reference to qNumber.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you passing strings to `setAnswer`?

Comment: I am doing that so I know which button is pressed - got the idea from another article here! Happy to do it another way if there's a better way of doing it! :)

Comment: @Sam_987: yes, but why a -string-? Why don’t you just use the plain numbers?

Comment: Also, the leading comma in your array declarations should be removed.

Comment: No reason other than that was how the example was set out. I have just tried removing the quote marks and making them numbers but it's still behaving the same.

Comment: The leading comma is there to stop my confusion with zero-indexing. Otherwise when ```qNumber``` is 5 it'll be referring to question 6 which is an element of confusion I don't need! :)

Comment: I would advice against such workarounds, as zero-indexing is ___very___ common, it's better to make sure you get comfortable with it.

Comment: The `questions` array contains a lot of references to variables which don't exist - and this is causing an error - you can see this in your browser's Console -  which halts your code and stops it creating the rightAnswers array on the next line. You don't seem to be using `questions` for anything, so just remove that line and then the rest of the code will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`q1` is referring to a variable `q1` that doesn't exist.  If you want the string `q1` you need to put it in quotes `"q1"`.  So line 2 `var questions = ...` is throwing an error, and the rest of it isn't finishing execution.  You need to fix that line.

```js
var qNumber = 1;
//var questions = [, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15];
var rightAnswers = [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3];
var answer = 0;

function setAnswer(choice) {
  answer = choice;
  checkAnswer();
}

function checkAnswer() {
  if (answer == rightAnswers[qNumber]) {
    alert("you got it right");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="answerA" onclick="setAnswer('1')">
  <div id="A">Answer 1 goes here</div>
</div>

<div class="answerB" onclick="setAnswer('2')">
  <div id="B">Answer 2 goes here</div>
</div>

<div class="answerC" onclick="setAnswer('3')">
  <div id="C">Answer 3 goes here</div>
</div>

<div class="answerD" onclick="setAnswer('4')">
  <div id="D">Answer 4 goes here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myQuestions = [
    {
        question: "What is 2+2?",
        answers: {
            a: '3',
            b: '5',
            c: '4'
        },
        correctAnswer: 'b'
    },
    {
        question: "What is blue?",
        answers: {
            a: 'dog',
            b: 'sky',
            c: 'chicken'
        },
        correctAnswer: 'a'
    }
];
```

You need some sort of better array and to do some sort of loop over it to generate the questions

Comment: True but this doesn't directly answer the question posed, and doesn't provide a complete usable alternative. It's a bit of an incomplete answer, maybe more of a comment.